# Python closing multiple Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I am using the example below from IBM website. I noticed that the threads for DatamineThread() and ThreadUrl() remain open because of the while-loops.

I am trying to terminate these threads and print text telling me so. I am not sure if I am going about this the correct way or even if the threads need to be terminated this way. The problem is when I set run = False in main() the while-loops are reading run = True.

Any help would be great... Thanks

```
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2
import time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

hosts = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://amazon.com",
        "http://ibm.com", "http://apple.com"]

queue = Queue.Queue()
out_queue = Queue.Queue()
run = True

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        global run
        while run:
            #grabs host from queue
            host = self.queue.get()

            #grabs urls of hosts and then grabs chunk of webpage
            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            chunk = url.read()

            #place chunk into out queue
            self.out_queue.put(chunk)

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

        print 'ThreadUrl finished...'


class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        global run
        while run:
            #grabs host from queue
            chunk = self.out_queue.get()

            #parse the chunk
            soup = BeautifulSoup(chunk)
            print soup.findAll(['title'])

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.out_queue.task_done()

        print 'DatamineThread finished...'

start = time.time()
def main():
    global run
    #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue, out_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    #populate queue with data
    for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

    for i in range(5):
        dt = DatamineThread(out_queue)
        dt.setDaemon(True)
        dt.start()


    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed
    queue.join()
    out_queue.join()

    # try and break while-loops in threads
    run = False

    time.sleep(5)


main()
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Can you provide the url to the IBM example?

Comment: The example is incorrect (wherever you got it). All the threads stop on waiting for an input from queues. The program finishes just because the child threads are daemonic and they exit when the main thread exits. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sgallen - Example Link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Comment: @khachik - Im new to python so just having a play. I was trying to understand how it exited, when threads where in a loop or waiting for a queued item. Am I to understand that if threads are set daemonic, that when the parent thread has finished the daemonic threads are forced to terminate? Is this the same for all parent threads or just main() thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not personally a huge fan of global variables for thread conditions, in large part because I've seen what you're encountering before.  The reason comes from the python docs for Queue.get.

> If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

Essentially, you're never seeing a second check against `while run:` because `out_queue.get()` has blocked indefinitely after the Queue empties out.

The better way to do this, IMHO, is to either use sentinel values in the Queues, or to use get_nowait and catch the exception to break the loop.  Examples:

### Sentinels

```
class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.out_queue.get()
            if data == "time to quit": break
            # non-sentinel processing here.
```

### Try / Except

```
class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.out_queue.get_nowait() # also, out_queue.get(False)
            except Queue.Empty: break
            # data processing here.
```

To ensure that all of your threads end, can do it a couple ways:

### Add Sentinels for each Worker

```
for i in range(numWorkers):
  out_queue.put('time to quit')

out_queue.join()
```

### Replace the Sentinel

```
class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.out_queue.get()
            if data == "time to quit": 
                self.out_queue.put('time to quit')
                break
            # non-sentinel processing here.
```

Either way should work.  Which is preferred depends on how the out_queue is populated.  If it can be added to / removed from by worker threads the first approach is preferable.  Call `join()`, then add the sentinels, then call `join()` again.  The second approach is good if you don't want to remember how many worker threads you created - it only uses one sentinel value and doesn't clutter the Queue.

Comment: Thanks for detailed help. I was going to try and do it with a sentinel but didn't know if it was best practice or it was called a sentinel :) Thanks again!

Comment: How would you end say 50 threads immediately working from the same queue? Only 1 thread will get the sentinel, Try / Except waits for all queued items to be processed. I think thats why I was trying to use a global. Do you have any sugguestions?

Comment: @arbme - You can do one of two things.  You can either load up a sentinel value for each thread, or you can have the thread put the sentinel back when it finds it so that the next thread finds it as well.  I'll add some extra code to demonstrate.

Comment: Once again thats the way I was going to try it but throught there might be a better way. Thanks again

Comment: It hangs on the final worker, you need self.out_queue.task_done() before you break the loops. Thanks again

Comment: Is there any way to make the threads terminate immediately? What I mean by this is, can they not jump to the front of the queue so they dont have to wait on the sentinel to be next in the queue. Thats why I was trying a global. Thanks

Comment: @arbme - The try / catch approach will make them die off as soon as there is no item waiting in the Queue.  `get()` blocks, `get_nowait()` or `get(False)` raise an exception if they don't find an item in the Queue.

Comment: So there is no way to jump to the front of the queue, like terminate immediately even if there are queued items left. I know sentianls can kind of do this but you still have to wait for it to come up in the queue. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @arbme - I am not quite sure I understand the question.  The call to `out_queue.join()` is going to block until the Queue is empty.  There's no way to interrupt that blocking operation to stop the worker threads early.  Removing the `while True` would make each worker handle 1 job and then terminate, if that would help you, but otherwise, I'm uncertain.